# Not working Socket java software

Tags: java, sockets, client-server

I created an simple server/client application,but I could not use this one with two parameters,so I want to add two numbers on server,Two numbers sent to server as parameter.
But When I sent two parameters to server,the client and server begun to wait for anything and nothing happened,as if running both of them without results.

Server

```
class Server3 public static void main(String[] args)
{  
    try 
      (
          ServerSocket server=new ServerSocket(12345);
          Socket client=server.accept();
          PrintWriter output=new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(),true);
          BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
     )
      {
          int result=0;
          String input;
          while((input=in.readLine())!=null)
          {
              System.out.println(input);
              result+=Integer.parseInt(input)*3;

              //output.println("The result to client is "+result);
              //output.flush();
          }
          output.println("The result to client is "+result);
          output.flush();
      }

}
```

}

Client

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


class Client3
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    try
      (
          Socket toServer=new Socket("localhost",12345);
          PrintWriter output=new PrintWriter(toServer.getOutputStream(),true);
          BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(toServer.getInputStream()));
      )
      {
          String temp,input;
          for(int i=0;i<args.length;++i)
          {
              output.println(args[i]);
              output.flush();
          }
          while((input=in.readLine())!=null);
          {
               input=in.readLine();

          }
          System.out.println(input);
      }

}
```

}

Do you hane any idea?
I tried a lot of things?
But never Can I use more numbers,I can use only without while condition.

Comment: -1 for futile tile. Try to summarize the actual problem in the title so you get readers who are interested in problems of that type,

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a **protocol** to communicate between client and server. It's just like a way to talk about or you can say some rules to be followed while talking.

---

Sample code: (Read inline comments)

> Here I used `DONE` as a token to tell the server that client has sent all the numbers and now I am waiting for the result.

Server:

Break the loop once all the numbers are received and sent the result back to client.

```
public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try (ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(12345);
            Socket client = server.accept();
            // flush automatically 
            PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(),true);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        client.getInputStream()));) {
            int result = 0;
            String input;
            while ((input = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(input);
                if (input.equals("DONE")) { // Server received token DONE
                    break;                  // break the loop
                }
                result += Integer.parseInt(input) * 3;
            }
            // sent the result back to client
            output.println("The result to client is " + result);
            // output.flush();
            // no need to call flush here 
            // because you have already set it to flush automatically 
        }
    }
}
```

---

Client:

You don't need to put a `while((input=in.readLine())!=null);` to wait for received result.

```
public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] a) throws Exception {
        try (Socket toServer = new Socket("localhost", 12345);
           // flush automatically 
           PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(toServer.getOutputStream(),true);
           BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        toServer.getInputStream()));) {                

            for (int i = 0; i < args.length; ++i) {
                output.println(args[i]); // sent all the numbers
                // output.flush();  
                // no need to call flush here 
                // because you have already set it to flush automatically 
            }
            output.println("DONE");  // Client sent token DONE
            String  input = in.readLine();   // read the result
            System.out.println(input);
        }

    }
}
```

output: (server)

```
1
2
DONE
```

output: (client)

```
The result to client is 9
```

Comment: Comments please. please please .

Comment: When I downvoted there were no inline comments at all. Now that here are I would add that it's far preferable to explain things in text, not in code, where they are hard to find.

Comment: @EJP I agree with you but sometime It's good to explain important line in the code itself. I'll take care it next time. **Thanks**

Comment: So I solved the problem,that mentioned in your comment.So thanks a lot.